# React NextJS 502 BAD_GATEWAY when navigating directly to inside url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, vercel

I have a react app, using NextJS
I have many links inside to inside my web pages, all works good

but when I am trying to navigate to the website not to the main page, I am getting message "502 BAD_GATEWAY"

for example:
navigate this link:
https://power-tools.co.il/
then click on the first tool from the right, you will successfully navigate to:
https://power-tools.co.il/rentals/generators

but if you try to navigate directly to the same url:
https://power-tools.co.il/rentals/generators

you will get error: "502 BAD_GATEWAY"

Why is that and how to fix?

This is the log of the runtime error on production:

```
info  - Loaded env from .env.production
2020-07-06T07:20:37.771Z    undefined   ERROR   Uncaught Exception  {"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"Must use import to load ES Module: /var/task/node_modules/flatted/cjs/index.js\nrequire() of ES modules is not supported.\nrequire() of /var/task/node_modules/flatted/cjs/index.js from /var/task/.next/serverless/pages/rentals/[categoryID].js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains \"type\": \"module\" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.\nInstead rename index.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove \"type\": \"module\" from /var/task/node_modules/flatted/package.json.\n","code":"ERR_REQUIRE_ESM","stack":["Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: /var/task/node_modules/flatted/cjs/index.js","require() of ES modules is not supported.","require() of /var/task/node_modules/flatted/cjs/index.js from /var/task/.next/serverless/pages/rentals/[categoryID].js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains \"type\": \"module\" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.","Instead rename index.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove \"type\": \"module\" from /var/task/node_modules/flatted/package.json.","","    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1149:13)","    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)","    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)","    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1019:19)","    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)","    at Object.U3Ae (/var/task/.next/serverless/pages/rentals/[categoryID].js:1964:18)","    at __webpack_require__ (/var/task/.next/serverless/pages/rentals/[categoryID].js:23:31)","    at Object.C8l3 (/var/task/.next/serverless/pages/rentals/[categoryID].js:1306:25)","    at __webpack_require__ (/var/task/.next/serverless/pages/rentals/[categoryID].js:23:31)","    at Module.wN1p (/var/task/.next/serverless/pages/rentals/[categoryID].js:4487:30)"]}
Unknown application error occurred
Error
```

Comment: Not only when navigating to a certain URL the server responds with `502`, it also responds with `502` on page reload for all the pages except for the home page. There is not enough information to work with here, please share the logs or check the logs yourself and share the part where the error is occurring.

Comment: The logs are showing only the build and deploy logs, not logs for trying to navigate

Comment: Does the app work locally? Not with `next dev` but after building the app. Try `next build && next start` and see if the error is reproducible.

Comment: yes, locally it work good, also able to navigate to direct inside url

Comment: I doubt that (I suggest check again with the script `next build && next start`), but since you are confirming that the app works perfectly in the local environment with the script `next build && next start` I think the error is not reproducible and it is not a good idea to just guess what is going wrong. Also since there are no logs, I suggest contacting vercel support or create a github issue.

Comment: I have added the log

Comment: Where are you hosting it?

Comment: in https://vercel.com/

Answer (score -1):

Since this is React, my suspicion is that Web server is not handling your app's routes properly.

As a possible solution, can you ensure that you have defined `"homepage"` in your `package.json` with the value of the URL of your website:

```
"homepage": "https://power-tools.co.il/",
```

and try to deploy it again?

Comment: I have added the log